Creating delayed Kafka consumer using ksqlDB
Below is my scenario.
I have the kafka topic: "incoming_messages" where it contains messages with below format
{
   "orderId": "5",
   "status": "st2",
   "timestamp": "2024-12-08T14:30:40.694243756Z"
}

I created a stream for above topic  with below command
CREATE STREAM incoming_messages (
    orderId STRING,
    status STRING,
    timestamp STRING
) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC='incoming_messages',
    VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
    TIMESTAMP='timestamp',
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSX'
);

Then I created a table using below command. I have added a hopping window because I need to consume messages in windowed mode with a delay
CREATE TABLE delayed_messages_table WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='delayed_messages', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON') AS
    SELECT
        orderId,
        LATEST_BY_OFFSET(orderId) AS order_Id,
        LATEST_BY_OFFSET(status) AS latest_status,
        LATEST_BY_OFFSET(timestamp) AS received_time
    FROM incoming_messages
    WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 10 SECONDS, ADVANCE BY 10 SECONDS)
    GROUP BY orderId
    EMIT CHANGES;

When I consumer from "delayed_messages" topic, it emits the changes without any delay.
Also, when I try to remove the kafka topic assignment from above table and create another stream to push those data to the topic. KSQL does not support persistent queries on windowed tables.
CREATE STREAM delayed_stream WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='delayed_messages', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON') AS
SELECT * 
FROM delayed_messages_table
EMIT CHANGES;



Try to create an intermediate topic. And in the consumer of the intermediate topic add delay and then stream back to the original "delayed_messages"

@SharadPaul you mean to add delay using consumer pause mechanism?
